# Zoom image with css3 animations

Tags: html, firefox, css

i want so zoom a picture. Webkit works fine, but Firefox is not working. Did i misspell something? I can't find anything...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Zoom Hover</title>
        <style type="text/css">

    @-moz-keyframes 'zoom' {
        0%{
            height:200px;
            width:200px;
            }
        100% {
                width: 1000px;
                height: 1000px;
            }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes 'zoom' {
        0%{
            height:200px;
            width:200px;
            }
        100% {
                width: 1000px;
                height: 1000px;
            }
    }    

img {
    width:200px;
    height:auto;

    }

img:hover {
    -moz-animation-name: 'zoom' 2s;
}
img:hover {
    -webkit-animation: 'zoom' 2s;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <img src="http://www.maplehilltree.com/CHRIST_PUNCHERS_HOOO__6_.jpg"/>

</body>
</html>
```

A demo you'll find here: http://jsfiddle.net/pDERw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mozilla doesn't support CSS3 animations [before version 5.0](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/5.0/releasenotes/). I found it:

You use `-moz-animation-name: 'zoom' 2s;`. You should use animation's shorthand property:

```
`-moz-animation: 'zoom' 2s;'
```

Also you shouldn't enclose animation name in `'` marks. See the update [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pDERw/2/), and please use Firefox version 5+.

Comment: @ Saeed Here it works lol : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davrous/archive/2011/12/06/introduction-to-css3-animations.aspx#intro

Answer (score 3):

-moz-animation **-name** is your problem but do not use -moz-animation for such a simple animation.

```
img {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    -moz-transition-duration: 2s; /* firefox */
    -webkit-transition-duration: 2s; /* chrome, safari */
    -o-transition-duration: 2s; /* opera */
    -ms-transition-duration: 2s; /* ie 9 */
}
img:hover {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/pDERw/1/)

Answer (score -2):

Put all your hover code in one css tag, maybe it's overwriting your previous css rules.